# How rename a remotefile before it is processed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I use spring integration to read and process files from a ftp server. So that the file is not processed by other processes, it should be renamed before processing. How can I do that with spring integration (spring boot)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Ben

Comment: Hello. Could you please share what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to have directories for the different stages:

1) waiting to be processed

2) being processed

3) error

4) done

If you create these directories, then different jobs can do different steps, one job can download files into 'waiting to be processed' then the process job can move the file to 'being processed', then on success it can move it to 'done' directory.

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html) is the best way to move a file in java 8.

If it is the case that multiple threads can access the ftp file and therefore they can not be processed locally, [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/rename-file-or-directory-on-ftp-server) is a snippet to rename a file on the remote server using [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)

Comment: I can not create direcories on the remote server.

Comment: Thx, for your help, but i need a spring integration solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Thx, for your help, but i need a spring integration solution

Use an [FTP OutboundGateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) configured with a `mv` command, then `GET` the renamed file.